# How can I change data dynamically?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a personal forecast with a networth forecast (goals) and an actual networth (realistic networth) and I used a 24.5% growth rate every month in my goal net worth forecast. But I would like to know how I can automatically change my networth forecast goal if my actual networth is higher already.

Check what I have here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WyJXEHm2M-QRP6zu1VfHIldd6nWP3EhT1r0WrzOiYC8/edit?usp=sharing

Can someone help me here?

Comment: can you provide an example in your sheet of what are you after?

Comment: Done. I have written what I need. :)

Answer (score 0):

try simple `IF` like:

```
=IF(C2<B2, (B2/100)*124.5, (C2/100)*124.5)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi. Thanks my friend. It's working. On the next sheet for 2021 I have
this formula:

=('Financial Forecast 2020'!B14/100)*124.5

How can I implement your code into this one?

Thanks.

Comment: depends on what exactly are you after... if B14 of 2020 sheet is smaller than C2 of 2021 (?) is that what you want to do?

Comment: I just want to continue as if it was one sheet so the formula must just continue. 

From march to april must be the same formula as from december to january. I check what you send but this doesn't work.

Comment: try: `=IF('Financial Forecast 2020'!C14<('Financial Forecast 2020'!B14/100)*124.5, ('Financial Forecast 2020'!B14/100)*124.5, ('Financial Forecast 2020'!C14/100)*124.5)`

Comment: Copy the formulas from that sheet to the next sheet. In the previous sheet you had entered "250" for January. Instead, for this sheet, use the same logic to construct another IF statement. Are you familiar with the IF statement syntax and how Sheets/Excel works? The syntax is ```=IF({condition},{result if true},{result if false})```

Answer (score 0):

A simple IF statement will work here.

In the "Networth Forecast" column, use an IF statement like so

{} = "Pseudo-code"

```
=IF({actual net worth > forecasted net worth}, {actual net worth + forcecasted increase},{forecasted net worth + forecasted increase})
```

However, shouldn't you always use the actual net worth to calculate the next forecasted net worth?

In that case, you'd want to use something like

```
=IF(ISBLANK({actual net worth cell}),{forcasted net worth + forecasted increase}, {actual net worth + forecasted increase})
```

Comment: Hi,

I want to achieve my goal so I have made a forecast first and then an actual networth. But if this actual networth is lower as the forecast of that month I must use the forecast to get back on track. If the actual networth is higher then the forecast I can get my next target based on my actual networth. You understand my point :)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The first IF statement should work for you then.